# Type Error: The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, typeerror

I am currently struggling to get my program working. What I am doing is connecting my database, which is a MySQL database on the workbench, and connecting it to my python. I am trying to store the user inputs as parameters in the stored procedure in my workbench. So when I hit submit the program will take the user input as parameters using the stored procedure. But I am running into several errors. The recurring one being this specific type of error.

Error Message : TypeError: The view function for 'signIn' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Python Imports/Code:

```
from flask import Flask, app, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
import MySQL.connector, CGI

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "<a href='/login'> login </a><br> <a href='/sign-up'> sign-up </a>"

@app.route('/sign-up', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def signIn():
    condition = 0
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='signlogpy', user='root', password='thereaper1999',
                                   port="3306")
    cursor = mydb.cursor()

    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        name = request.form["name"]
        displayName = request.form["displayName"]
        DOB = request.form["dateOfBirth"]
        args = [email, password, name, displayName, DOB]
    else:
        return print("Could not reveice user input")
    if condition == 0:
        condition = 1
    elif condition == 1:
        results = cursor.callproc('signInInformation', args)
        cursor.execute('select * from signin')
        cursor.fetchall()
    else:
        return render_template("SignUp.html")

    signInInformationProc = cursor.callproc('signInInformation', args)

    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print(results)
    if results == True:
        print("works")
        redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        render_template("SignUp.html")
    return redirect(url_for(login))

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('Login.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)



Workbench MySql code: 
use signlogpy;

DELIMITER $$
    create procedure signInInformation 
    (
        in
            p_userEmail varchar(45),
            p_userPassword varchar(45),
            p_name varchar(45),
            p_displayName varchar(45),
            p_dob date
    )
begin
    insert into signin (userEmail, userPassword, name, displayName, dob)
    values (p_userEmail, p_userPassword, p_name, p_displayName, p_dob);
end $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If anybody does reply I do thank you immensely and appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: I just updated the question including the error. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the declaration of args is inside

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

which means that args doesn't have any meaning outside and after that if statement. Try putting

```
args = []
```

at the beginning of signIn() which will let it be accessible by the whole function.